# How to scale only one game object in the AR scene in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

so I have like 5 game object in my scene but I only scale each of them separately. However when I try to do that all of them start scaling simultaneously. Also, I have a placement indicator that would be used to instantiate the object on the plane. It seems that instead of the object itself, the placement indicator is the one that gets scaled. How should I fix that?

I have tried deactivating the placement indicator but did not work.

Here is the code for instantiating objects:

I limited the obj number to 5. 
I use this script instead of the usual "PlaceonPlane" script.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.XR;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;

public class ARTaptoPlaceObject : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private ARSessionOrigin arOrigin;
    GameObject spawnedobj;
    public GameObject placementIndicator;
    private ARRaycastManager arRaycast; 
    public Pose placementPose;
    public UIContoller sc; 
    public bool placementPoseIsValid = false;
    private int count;
    private string valu;
    string prefabs;

    void Start()
    {
        arOrigin = FindObjectOfType<ARSessionOrigin>();
        arRaycast = FindObjectOfType<ARRaycastManager>();
        count = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        UpdatePlacementPose();
        UpdatePlacementIndicator(); 

        for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                if (placementPoseIsValid && Input.GetTouch(i).tapCount == 2)
                {
                    PlaceObject();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void PlaceObject()
    {
        if (count <= 4)
        {
            if (sc.objectToPlace != null)
            {
                spawnedobj = Instantiate(sc.objectToPlace, placementPose.position, placementPose.rotation);
                arOrigin.MakeContentAppearAt(spawnedobj.transform, spawnedobj.transform.position, spawnedobj.transform.rotation);
                count++;
            }

        }
        else
        {
                placementIndicator.SetActive(false); 
        }
    }

    private void UpdatePlacementIndicator()
    {
        if (placementPoseIsValid && count <= 4 && sc.active == false)
        {
            placementIndicator.SetActive(true);
            placementIndicator.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(placementPose.position, placementPose.rotation);
        }
        else
        {
            placementIndicator.SetActive(false); 
        }
    }
    private void UpdatePlacementPose()
    {
        var screenCenter = Camera.current.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f));
        var hits = new List<ARRaycastHit>();
        arRaycast.Raycast(screenCenter, hits, UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.TrackableType.Planes);
        placementPoseIsValid = hits.Count > 0;
        if (placementPoseIsValid)
        {
            placementPose = hits[0].pose;

            var cameraForward = Camera.current.transform.forward;
            var cameraBearing = new Vector3(cameraForward.x, 0, cameraForward.z).normalized;
            placementPose.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(cameraBearing);

        }
    }

}
```

and here is the Scaler script that's attached to the button that would scale the object.

```
public class Scaler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UIContoller uc;
    public ARTaptoPlaceObject ap; 
    private GameObject ReferenceToScale;

    public void OnValueChange()
    {
        ReferenceToScale = (UnityEngine.GameObject)Resources.Load(uc.s_count, typeof(GameObject));
        Vector3 t = ReferenceToScale.transform.localScale;

        Vector3 scaleValue = t * 1.1f;

        ReferenceToScale.transform.localScale = scaleValue;
    }
```

Also the "objectToPlace" itself is in the "UI.Controller" script as I could not view it in the scene when it was in the "ARTaptoPlace" script

Comment: How are your objects structured in your scene? Do they share the same parent? How are you scaling them through `Transform.Scale`, `Transform.localScale`, or in the Inspector?

Comment: @Eliasar I added the scripts